# Como inserir conteúdo HTML na div com jQuery sem usar \" (barra inversa e aspas duplas)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu uso um CMS chamado uCoz e ele tem uma variável `<?$RELATED_ENTRIES$(5)?>` que exibe postagens relacionadas a da página que meu visitante lendo. Eu gostaria de colocar os linques relacionados entre o texto da postagem, mas não funciona por regra do sistema CMS, que não tem o root dos scripts aberto.

A solução que encontrei foi criar um `<div class="related"></div>` e inserir o conteúdo que a variável `<?$RELATED_ENTRIES$(5)?>` gerar usando jQuery. Mas no Javascript as aspas duplas tem que colocar `\` (barra inversa) antes e o código gerado não tem esta `\` (barra inversa)

O código que a variável gera é assim

```
<ul class="uRelatedEntries">
<li class="uRelatedEntry"><a href="/link#1">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li class="uRelatedEntry"><a href="/link#2">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
<li class="uRelatedEntry"><a href="/link#3">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
```

Só que o HTML é compacto em um linha só.

Comment: Se compreendí bem, você obtem o HTML que precisa só que ele aparece na mesma linha, sem ser organizado em listas?

Comment: Pode mostrar o código que você está usando no momento?

Comment: Está meio difícil de entender, realmente seria bom você colocar o código que você está usando para gerar isso e como você queria que fosse.

Comment: e qual o seu problema?

Comment: Conforme eu entendi, o uCoz substitui o `<?$RELATED_ENTRIES$(5)?>` automaticamente pelo HTML que consta na pergunta. Ele quer usar essa string HTML que o uCoz fornece usando JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: Ao mencionar a questão do *escaping* (necessidade de barra inversa antes das aspas), revela que esse é o problema: como fazer o escaping de uma variável que ele não tem acesso para modificar (mas apenas para utilizar no seu *template*)?

Comment: @J.Bruni, acho que quando o usuário explicar melhor todos vamos ter mais certezas. Por enquanto é melhor não comentar em demasia, ou adivinhar. Se a questão não for clarificada em 24 horas, votamos para fechar.

Comment: @J.Bruni, optimo. Você já respondeu. Quando a pergunta for clarificada eu voto +1 se você tiver acertado. Até lá não tenho certeza do que está a ser perguntado por isso aguardo antes de responder.

Comment: @J.Bruni: [podemos falar no chat?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) Quem votou negativo nõ explicou, daí o meu comentário a tentar explicar porque pode ter sido...

Comment: Tive a mesma interpretação do @J.Bruni, mesmo concordando que a pergunta da espaço para dúvidas, mas acho que essa batalha pelo perfeccionismo é meio frívola. É de direito um usuário não saber formular tão bem sua pergunta e uma resposta ser acerca do entendimento, não vejo motivo para não pontua-lo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neste caso, envolva a variável entre aspas simples:

```
$('div.related').html('<?$RELATED_ENTRIES$(5)?>');
```

Só teria que colocar `\` (barra inversa) antes das aspas duplas caso a variável estivesse entre aspas duplas: `"<?$RELATED_ENTRIES$(5)?>"` (desse jeito não funciona porque precisaria da barra inversa).

Porém, mesmo envolvendo a variável com aspas simples conforme sugerido, caso apareçam aspas simples no conteúdo da variável, aí você precisaria da barra inversa antes delas.

Em suma:

- Se o conteúdo da variável tiver aspas duplas, envolva ela com aspas simples.
- Se o conteúdo da variável tiver aspas simples, envolva ela com aspas duplas.
- Se o conteúdo da variável tiver ambas aspas simples e duplas, você não vai conseguir utilizar o texto sem que possa alterá-lo (o que não é possível pelo sistema do uCoz).

Comment: Obrigado. Resolveu o meu problema. Agradeço por me ajudar e explicar. Ainda estou começando com programação web e agradeço de coração a ajuda.